# Location of /home/airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have specified 3 nodes when creating a cloud composer environment. I tried to connect to worker nodes via SSH but  I am not able to find airflow directory in /home. So where exactly is it located?

Comment: Try `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Composer runs Airflow [on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#google-kubernetes-engine), so you won't find data directly on any of the host GCE instances. Instead, Airflow processes are run within Kubernetes-managed containers, which [either mount or sync data](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#data_synchronization) to the `/home/airflow` directory. To find the directory you will need to look *within* a running container.

Since each environment stores its Airflow data in a GCS bucket, you can alternatively inspect files by using Cloud Console or `gsutil`. If you really want to view `/home/airflow` with a shell, you can use `kubectl exec` which allows you to run commands/open a shell on any pod/container in the Kubernetes cluster. For example:

```sh
# Obtain the name of the Composer environment's GKE cluster
$ gcloud composer environments describe $ENV_NAME

# Fetch Kubernetes credentials for that cluster
$ gcloud container cluster get-credentials $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME
```

Once you have Kubernetes credentials, you can list running pods and SSH into them:

```sh
# List running pods
$ kubectl get pods

# SSH into a pod
$ kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME bash
airflow-worker-a93j$ ls /home/airflow
```

Comment: I just tried this and I can't see any of the workers when I list pods?

Comment: Check for the Composer namespace: `kubectl get ns | grep composer`.

Comment: Ended up doing `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and that worked. Did not realize it wouldn't do all namespaces by default.